# Android Things UDP Socket over IPv6

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp, android-things

There is pretty much no error logs but it can't actually send anything over mesh network on udp. Seems to receive without any issues but on send it doesn't go.

```
try {
sock = new DatagramSocket(null);
udpPacket = new DatagramPacket(data.getBytes(), data.length(), InetAddress.getByName(deviceAddr), portServer);


sock.send(udpPacket);
Log.e(TAG, "Connection send: " + data);

if (!sock.isClosed()) {
sock.close();
Log.e(TAG, "Socket Closed");
}
} catch (SocketException e) {
Log.e(TAG, "Socket Issue: " + e.getMessage());
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
Log.e(TAG, "Host Issue: " + e.getMessage());
} catch (IOException e) {
Log.e(TAG, "IO Issue: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

thats the code for send over udp.

Here is the addr: fdde:ad00:beef:0:8142:58d9:a2a3:7377 port is 1212 and on receive there are no trouble. I have no more ideas did try quite a lot with the code and workarounds but without any solution. The other devices on the network seem to communicate with each other without no issue on udp send and receive.

Any thoughts?

Comment: How come you are receiving while not sending?

Comment: Exactly i have no idea. Thats exactly whats happening. I thought its the thread it wasn't checked very well everything.